# Does it make sense to pool pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm certainly sure about the java which using a pool of threads would help the performance and the stability of the program.

So does it make sense with pthread and native application in C too?

If we assume we would control the max amount of threads using a semaphore, so what about the next part? creating a pthread is so heavy? pooling it is recommended?

Comment: It really depends on the use-case, there's no generic "yes"/"no" answer.

Comment: Assume each pthread will process a http request @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: In that specific use-case then yes thread-pools are probably a good idea. No semaphore needed though, unless you want to be able to modify the size of the pool dynamically at run-time.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's good becasue the number of thread going to be too much? or they are going to do same stuff? Except this case, what are the factors to have or not?

Comment: Put it this way.  Signaling a thread that already exists, eg. by pushing a work request object/struct onto a producer-consumer queue, where free threads are waiting on a semaphore, is ~100 times faster than creating a thread from scratch.  This reduces overhead, especially with shorter work units.